# How to remove password requirement for every folder and file I open

Tags: permissions, password

Every time I access a folder and file within SharePoint the system asks for my password. How can I modify SharePoint as a user to recognize the libraries/folders I have permissions for without having to enter my password every time?

Comment: Are you the AD user and having permissions on the required folders and files you are trying to access. Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Set IE login in security to automatic Login using current name and password.

That gets access to the Intranet without loin being needed.

Then add the site to Trusted Sites or Intranet (depending on environment) and then Office files should open right away too.